# XML Mapper issue in Mybatis

Tags: mybatis, mapper

nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error creating document instance.  Cause: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.

this is the syntax

it working well while fetching the result in ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER
but while start my local server it gives error
please suggest what need to fix on this
SQL is good and working to get records directly from DB

```
select 
rownum test,
  os_alternate_label "altlabel",
  em_customs_bar_code "label",
  em_source_appl "source",
  'H5' "altoutcome",
  DECODE(OS_NL_DO_NOT_LOAD,1,'NL',  
  DECODE(OS_H5_ALT_DUP_HOLD,1,'H5',  
  DECODE(OS_BD_RTS_EC,1,'BD',  
  DECODE(OS_H2_EC_HOLD,1,'H2',  
  DECODE(OS_HD_NO_DISP_HOLD,1,'HD',  
  DECODE(OS_H3_CBP_HOLD,1,'H3',  
  DECODE(OS_H4_USPIS_HOLD,1,'H4',  
  DECODE(OS_UD_RTS_CUSTOMER,1,'UD',  
  DECODE(OS_NQ_EU_WAIT_TIME,1,'NQ',  
  DECODE(OS_H1_iPASS_HOLD,1,'H1',  
  DECODE(OS_DG_DANGER_HOLD,1,'DG',  
  DECODE(OS_CC_COMM_HOLD,1,'CC',  
  DECODE(OS_H6_CUS_DUP_HOLD,1,'H6',  
  DECODE(OS_RL_RELEASE,1,'RL','XX')))))))))))))) "customoutcome",  
  em_destination_country "destCo",
  em_recipient_last_name "tolastName",
  em_recipient_business "tobusinessname",
  em_recipient_address "toaddress",
  em_recipient_city "tocity",
  em_recipient_state "toregionprov",
  em_recipient_postcode "postcode",
  to_char(em_date_time_received,'MM/DD/YY HH24:MI') "timeReceived"
FROM CUSTOMS.OUTCOME_STATUS_T,  
      CUSTOMS.ECM_MANIFEST_T  
 WHERE OS_CUSTOMS_BAR_CODE = EM_CUSTOMS_BAR_CODE
```

Answer (score 0):

Use escape character I believe the '/' used to define date is causing problem

```
<![CDATA[ 
    select 
rownum test,
  os_alternate_label "altlabel",
  em_customs_bar_code "label",
  em_source_appl "source",
  'H5' "altoutcome",
  DECODE(OS_NL_DO_NOT_LOAD,1,'NL',  
  DECODE(OS_H5_ALT_DUP_HOLD,1,'H5',  
  DECODE(OS_BD_RTS_EC,1,'BD',  
  DECODE(OS_H2_EC_HOLD,1,'H2',  
  DECODE(OS_HD_NO_DISP_HOLD,1,'HD',  
  DECODE(OS_H3_CBP_HOLD,1,'H3',  
  DECODE(OS_H4_USPIS_HOLD,1,'H4',  
  DECODE(OS_UD_RTS_CUSTOMER,1,'UD',  
  DECODE(OS_NQ_EU_WAIT_TIME,1,'NQ',  
  DECODE(OS_H1_iPASS_HOLD,1,'H1',  
  DECODE(OS_DG_DANGER_HOLD,1,'DG',  
  DECODE(OS_CC_COMM_HOLD,1,'CC',  
  DECODE(OS_H6_CUS_DUP_HOLD,1,'H6',  
  DECODE(OS_RL_RELEASE,1,'RL','XX')))))))))))))) "customoutcome",  
  em_destination_country "destCo",
  em_recipient_last_name "tolastName",
  em_recipient_business "tobusinessname",
  em_recipient_address "toaddress",
  em_recipient_city "tocity",
  em_recipient_state "toregionprov",
  em_recipient_postcode "postcode",
  to_char(em_date_time_received,'MM/DD/YY HH24:MI') "timeReceived"
FROM CUSTOMS.OUTCOME_STATUS_T,  
      CUSTOMS.ECM_MANIFEST_T  
 WHERE OS_CUSTOMS_BAR_CODE = EM_CUSTOMS_BAR_CODE
 ]]>
```